# как сделать GET запрос

Tags: javascript, api, get

Всем привет, передо-мной стоит задача  отправить запрос с параметрами на Dark Sky API, получить в ответ что-то, записать это, обработать это что-то, и вывести нужные значения на страницу, моя проблема заключается в том что я не могу найти информацию о том, как мне это осуществить на javascript. Спасибо.

Comment: Скорее всего твоя проблема в том, что ты не стал изучать основы ЯП, а сразу кинулся делать то, что не под силу, хотя после 2-3 месяцев изучения уже представлял бы что имеется в виду

Comment: прохожу freecodecamp, там дают всю инфу постепенно, но на JSON APIs and Ajax они дали очень мало инфы, после который я толком ничего не понял.

Comment: я знаю что имеется в виду, я не знаю как отправить сам запрос, и как подставить в него переменные которые являются параметрами для запроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

посмотри здесь

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40015269/using-fields-to-complete-an-api-call-dark-sky-forecast-api

```
                <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script>
                //Waits until document is ready to run
                jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                    //Beginning of code
                    //Makes the request
                    $.ajax({
                    url : "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/MyKey/1111,-1111+?exclude=minutely,hourly,daily,alerts,flags",
                    dataType : "jsonp",
                    success : function(parsed_json) {
                    var location = parsed_json['timezone'];
                    var temp_f = parsed_json['currently']['temperature'];
                    var complete = ("Current temperature in " + location + " is: " + temp_f);
                    $('#random').html("<h1>" + complete + "</h1>")
                    }
                    });
                    }
                });

                </script>

                    $('#search').click(getInfo);
                });

                </script>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я постараюсь найти информацию о том как мне написать это самому.